# Facebook page post appers as Admin Name instead of Page Name while using link param

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook php sdk for posting feed on page's wall and using following parameters to post feed on my page.

$data['link'] = "URL";

$data['picture'] = "Image URL";

$data['caption'] = "caption name";

$data['name'] = "Page Title";

$data['message'] = "Message";

$data['description'] = "Description";

All things were working fine till i had not added $data['link'] param but when i added $data['link'] param and run the script then feed post as username not as page's name.

e.g.

Username : Ashvins

Page name : Ashvin Community

Before data['link'] :: Ashvin Community => Test Message 28 minutes ago

After data['link'] :: AshvinS => Test Message 20 minutes ago

Is there any problems with link param or may i have done something wrong ? Please guide me for proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved now there are different access keys for page and user we have to get page access key using user access key with below code:

$acToken = "user access token";

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$acToken;

$accounts = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

print_r($accounts);

exit;

Array will return you all page information with page access key and it will use for page related operations.

Thanks, Ashvin surela